# Regex formula for e-mail parsing of Instead @ to -> (at)

Tags: php, regex, parsing

Here is the code that parses Text for e-mails

```
<?php

 $res = preg_match_all(
    "/[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\\.[a-z]{2,}/i",
    $text,
    $matches
  );

?>
```

but I must re-modify it to

INSTEAD

> @

to parse for

> (at)

How to modify the regex formula?

Comment: do you want to scrap emails and spam them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple: replace

```
@
```

with

```
\(at\)
```

:

```
$res = preg_match_all(
    "/[a-z0-9]+([_\.-][a-z0-9]+)*\(at\)([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\.[a-z]{2,}/i",
    $text,
    $matches
  );
```

Note that the double `backslash:

```
\\.
```

Isn't necessary to escape the dot.

Instead, it is necessary to escape `(` and `)` because they are [meta-characters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php) in the regex.

Also, as suggested in the comments, you can get either emails with `@` and `(at)` with a unique Regex:

```
/[a-z0-9]+([_\.-][a-z0-9]+)*(@|\(at\))([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\.[a-z]{2,}/i
```

Comment: This of course depends  if he wants to keep matching the original values as well, in that case, you can use a character-class with an or `[@|at]`

Comment: @MattSmeets `(@|\(at\))`

Answer (score -1):

Rather than using RegEx to find if the email is valid, you can use the [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) method.

```
<?php
$email = "john.doe@example.com";

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  echo("$email is a valid email address");
} else {
  echo("$email is not a valid email address");
}
?>
```

An example can be found on a tutorial from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_email.asp)

Comment: This does not really answer this question since OP asked to make `(at)` match as a valid email (at least that is how it seems)